# Sizing down winter tires from old car?

Tags: tires, winter

have tires from our previous car and not sure if they are trasnferable to the new car. I get the speed difference, is there any other issue apart from that or is this ok? Its size down winter tire. If not can I re-use the rim with a new tire?
[image]

Comment: It's unclear which is which between 'new car / old car' and 'current size / new size. If you are putting on a smaller tyre it will be more inclined to lose traction, because it will transmit more torque to the road. Is that advisable for a winter tyre? You could contemplate trading in the previous tyres/wheels.